# FileOutputStream head pointer

Tags: java, android, file-io

I am looking for some confirmation that `FileOutputStream` works like I think it does.  I am downloading a file and, if I lose the network connection, trying to resume the download from where it left off.

How I am trying to do this is to open the FileOutputStream as not appending and then writing nothing at an offset.  My question is will that work or does opening it as non appending delete the contents?  Also if I write at an offset will it continue to write after that position in the file on subsequent calls to write?

```
File outFile = new File(outFileName);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

long fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
int status = DOWNLOADING;

connection.connect();
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
long downloaded = in.skip(outFile.length());

publishProgress(downloaded, fileSize);

try
{
        int read = 0;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

        // Skip ahead in the out buffer
        out.write(buffer, (int)downloaded, read);

        while(status == DOWNLOADING)
        {
                if(!NetworkUtils.isConnected(_context))
                {
                        // This breaks us out of the doInBackground in the AsyncTask
                        _downloadFailed = true;
                        throw new Exception("Network Connectivity Lost!");
                }

                read = in.read(buffer);

                if(read == -1) 
                {
                        publishProgress(fileSize);
                        break;
                }

                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                downloaded += read;

                publishProgress(downloaded);
        }
}
finally
{
        out.close();        
        in.close();
        connection.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also take a look at the `RandomAccessFile` class, which will let you seek to a certain position and start writing from there without truncating the file.

Comment: That is going to be helpful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [api doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) more carefully.

Opening a FileOutputStream in non-append more always erases the contents of the file and writes at the beginning. Moreover, the offset argument of the write method is an offset from the beginning of the data (the byte array argument), not from the beginning of the file.

You should just open the stream in append mode, and start writing when you have read n bytes of data, n being the number of bytes already present in the file.

Comment: Sorry but you need to read the api doc more carefully. If your buffer size that you use to write bytes to the file is lower than the offset, the write method throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. The download can be paused at any moment, so the offset probably 99.9999% of times will be higher than the buffer size (1024 for example). The solution is to use a RandomAccessFile with seek method.

Comment: I haven't understood one word of your comment. My answer just says that the `off` argument of the `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` method is an offset from the beginning of the `b` argument, and not from the beginning ot the file where the stream writes. If you know that the file already contains n bytes, and you are downloading m bytes, where m > n, you can open the file in append mode, ignore the first n downloaded bytes, and only write the (m - n) last downloaded bytes.